# How do I make my C# class work with the JSON reply to avoid JSON Serialization error?

Tags: c#, json, .net

I am currently working on a project and ran into some issues and I was hoping someone with a better experience could point me in the right direction. I am trying to create a class that corresponds with my JSON response so I can use the extracted information to fill a table. However, I keep on receiving the error message:

> “Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'BankRepDet' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly. To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List<T> that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.”

I tried the `JsonArray` attribute above my `BankRepDet` class and that gave out the error:

> Cannot create and populate list type BankRepDet.”

I am supposed to get the `accountId` for the "VALUE TO BE EXTRACTED", for the "savingType": "THIS CONDITION". I tried the `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LinkResponseDetails>(jsonResponse);`, but it’s also not working. I felt like the class made sense since according to the JSON response response detail is an object that contains an array of accounts.

Code:

```cs
namespace Namespace
{
    internal class BankInfo 
    {
        public BankReqDet request { get; set; }
        public BankRepDet response { get; set; }

        public class Request 
        {
            public RequestHeader requestHeader { get; set; }
            public BankReqDet requestDetails { get; set; }

            public Request()
            {
                requestHeader = new RequestHeader();
                requestDetails = new BankReqDet();
            }
        }

        public class Response 
        {
            public ResponseHeader responseHeader { get; set; }
            public BankRepDet responseDetails { get; set; }
        }

        public BankInfo()
        {
            request = new Request();
        }
    }
    public class BankReqDet
    {
        public guid id1{ get; set; }
        public Guid id2{ get; set; }
        public int id3 { get; set; }
    }

    public class Accounts
    {
        public Guid accountId{ get; set; }
        public string accountType { get; set; }
        public AccountObject accountObject { get; set; }
    }

    public class AccountObject
    {
        public Card card {get; set; }
        public string savingType { get; set; }
        public string savingName { get; set; }
        public int amount { get; set; }
        public string frequency { get; set; }
        public Balance balance { get; set; }
        public Benefit[] benefits { get; set; }
    }

    public class Balance
    {
        public int av { get; set; }
        public int led{ get; set; }
    }

public class Benefit ()
{
     public string benefitType { get; set; }
    public string benefitName { get; set; }

}

public class Card ()
{
     public string cardLastFour { get; set; }
     public int balance { get; set; }

}

    public class BankRepDet
    {
        public Accounts[] Accounts { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Response:

```json
{
    "responseHeader": {
        "responseId": "",
        "responseCode": "OK",
        "responseSubCode": "",
        "responseMessage": "successful"
    },
    "responseDetails": [
        {
            "accountId": "……”
            "accountType": "card",
            "accountObject": {
                "card": {
                    "cardLastFour": "……",
                    "balance": 0,
                    
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "accountId": "VALUE TO BE EXTRACTED",
            "accountType": "",
            "accountObject": {
                "savingType": "THIS CONDITION",
                "savingName": "",
                "amount": 0,
                "frequency": "",
                "balance": {
                    "available": 25,
                    "ledger": 25
                },
                "benefits": [
                    {
                        "benefitType": "",
                        "benefitName": "",
                        
                    },
                    {
                        "benefitType": "",
                        "benefitName": "",
                    },
                    {
                        "benefitType": "",
                        "benefitName": "",
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "accountId": "",
            "accountType": "",
            "accountObject": {
                "savingType": "",
                "savingName": "",
                "amount": 0,
                "frequency": "",
                "balance": {
                    "available": 0,
                    "ledger": 0
                },
                "benefits": []
            }
        }
        
    ]
}
```

In the API description, next to the `accountObject`, there has been a mention of `oneOf` keyword and the options are either card or saving account with an array of benefits, both of which are present in the JSON body. How can I change my class to better fit the JSON body so as to stop getting this response?

Based on the JSON reply and the model of response from the API, I tried to make the response detail class to be an object which contains an array of the accounts object. I don't understand why that is not working though.

Comment: The error message says that your JSON contains an array, but your C# model is a single object.

Comment: Your `BankReqDet` object doesn't seem look like any of your JSON structure, and the same goes for `BankInfo`, so I don't see how the JSON and C# go together really.

Comment: The BankReqDet has a seprate json request body that was able to go through without these errors.  The BankRepDet  is supposed to represent the responseDetails of the json body or at least that's what  I was attempting to do. i probably should have incuded my other class that gets the response header sorted out but while debugging, it was the BankRepDet  that seemed to be causing the issue.

Comment: `"responseDetails": [` vs `public BankRepDet responseDetails { get; set; }` ... it should (probably) be `public BankRepDet[] responseDetails { get; set; }` (or a collection type).

Comment: Code you posted can not even be compiled. If you really need some help post the real code.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the `responseDetails` property of your `Response` class probably needs to be of type `Accounts[]`. Get rid of the `BankReqDet` class.